# Method to keep SSAS model up to date?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, ssas-tabular

Is there a provided way to keep SSAS models in DirectQuery mode up to date with any database changes?
i.e. If new table, new columns are added either be notified or preferably have SSAS models automatically updated

I know SQL Server has a notification option, but was hoping for another method that might be able to automatically update this SSAS model to reflect the database

Comment: please follow this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188547

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana That link only address data changes, not the structural changes the OP has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

For structural changes to the SSAS Data Model, such as adding table, modifying columns in the tables and relationships etc you have to modify the model in Visual Studio/SSDT and deploy those changes to the SSAS Database.

Best practice is to have some sort of process to understand, add and deploy changes to a database and data model, so you can accommodate any changes and test them before release.